# Delete user after Contact Form 7 submission

Tags: users, plugin-contact-form-7

I need to allow users to delete their accounts on the front end, but need to collect some information about their reason for leaving. I'm using Contact Form 7 to collect the info, and want to use a hook to delete the user.

When I use the function below, I receive an email with the info from the form, but it doesn't delete the user.

```
function outta_here() {

    global $current_user;
    $delete_me = get_currentuserinfo();

    wp_delete_user($delete_me->ID);
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'outta_here' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. get_currentuserinfo() returns the data into some preset global variables. Try this:

```
function outta_here() {

    global $user_ID;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    wp_delete_user($user_ID);
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'outta_here' );
```

You can read more about get_currentuserinfo() on [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo).